# How to write in a less cumbersome way an extension method for generic Interface with a constraint

Tags: c#

```
interface interface1<Coordinate> where Coordinate : IComparable<Coordinate>
{
    Coordinate getPosition(XYZ p);
}

static class CreateOrderOnASpaceExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderElements<Coordinate, T>(this interface1<Coordinate> myInterface, IEnumerable<T> elements, Func<T, XYZ> elementToPoint)
        where Coordinate : IComparable<Coordinate>
    =>
    elements.OrderBy(
        x => myInterface.getPosition(elementToPoint(x)),
        Comparer<Coordinate>.Create((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y)
        )
    );
}
```

Should I really write `where Coordinate : IComparable<Coordinate>` in the extension method declaration?

I already said that `Coordinate` is comparable when I created `interface1`.

Without that :

> There is no boxing convertion or type paramater convertion from Coordinate to Comparable

Comment: As an aside, I'm finding it really confusing that `Coordinate` is a type parameter name. I'd suggest following the normal .NET naming convention of making it `TCoordinate` - and then rename both the interface (from `interface1`) and the method within it (from `getPosition`). The more realistic you can make your question code, the less distracting it is.

Comment: The ultimate goal of this snippet feels a bit contrived and I'm sensing an XY problem, but without context it is unclear whether this approach is valid or not. I suspect you may be doubling up on something that you don't quite need, but we'd need to see the context to accurately judge that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use `===` to show to which part the `where` applies in each of your generic definitions:

```
interface interface1<Coordinate>
                     ==========
                     where Coordinate : IComparable<Coordinate>
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
static class CreateOrderOnASpaceExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderElements<Coordinate, T>(this interface1<Coordinate> myInterface, IEnumerable<T> elements, Func<T, XYZ> elementToPoint)
                                                      ==========
                                                      where Coordinate : IComparable<Coordinate>
}
```

*Without* the 2nd `where`, the compiler will see that you are trying to feed an *unconstrained* type `Coordinate` (which could then be anything) into `interface1<>`, which *has a constraint*, making the *unconstrained* `Coordinate` not allowed.

The fact that `interface1` has a constraint does not mean that the "world" outside of it will magically also be restricted if you try to connect it; it already needs to fit before it can be allowed.

An analogy: you made a railroad which requires trains. You first need to make a train, and then you can put in on the railroad. There's no magic that makes any vehicle that you put on it a train.